# Activiti: Rest Api paging

Tags: java, activiti

I have 500 process instances in activiti. I am retrieving them by using REST Api pagination

> /runtime/tasks?processDefinitionId=test:1:1212&includeProcessVariables=true&start=0&size=10

It works until **start=125&size=10**. However I use high value for **start=105&size=10**, return nothing. I remove **includeProcessVariables=true** from query param, pagination works again.

This question is also asked in [alfresco community](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/226715-rest-api-paging), no answers reply.

Comment: do you see any error on the server?

Comment: No errors is shown 

Comment: what activiti version do you use?

Comment: I am using Activiti 6.0 bro.